# Limit the zoomband / constant line to certain X axis

Tags: lightningchart

we are creating bands and lines using below code

```
const constantline = axis.addConstantLine()

const band = axis.addBand()
const constantLline = axis.addConstantLine(false)
const band = axis.addBand(false)

constantline.setValue( 50 )
```

But line is extending to full x or y axis , can we limit the X or y axis like Rectangle ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to limit the constant line or band to only be drawn to a specific value. The constant line and band will always span across the chart.

Comment: can we do it via rectangle or something based on x axis and y axis